# Bad shadow Flutter

Tags: flutter

[Bad shadows 1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RexNj.)

[Bad shadows 2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Ga4.png)

Hello everybody! I encountered the fact that FloatingActionButton and pop-up card (`alert Dialog`) have very bad shadows. They look like a solid black frame. If I change the color of the rear background on white, then the shadows become normal. However, I want to leave a dark gray background. How can I solve this problem with shadows?

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[700],
        child: Icon(
          Icons.create,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SearchScreen(),
              ));
        },
      ),
```

And pop-up card

```
                             AlertDialog(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(23.0),
                                  ),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red[400],
                                  content: Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                          1.2,
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                                              4,
                                      constraints:
                                          BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400),
                                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            TextButton(
                                                child: const Text(
                                                  'Delete dialog',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black),
                                                ),
                                                onPressed: () {}),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                ),
```

Comment: What is the exact color you're using for the background?

Comment: @Mobina grey[900]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the dialog. For the `FloatingActionButton`, reduce the `elevation` (e.g. `elevation: 2`).

Comment: Same I cant reproduce the issue with the exact same colors even with 10 elevation for the FAB (also, one of your link is broken)